# Using different passport in home country

Tags: dual-nationality, malaysia

I have used a Taiwan passport to go to my home country, Malaysia, for the past recent years and I am thinking of using my Malaysian passport to go to Malaysia again. Does it work?

Comment: In general, yes, but I'm unaware of any considerations that might exist specific to Malaysia.

Comment: @phoog Malaysia doesn’t allow dual citizenship. AFAIK